# ¿Como configurar el tiempo de expiración de mi JWT?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt

Estoy realizando una aplicación web api con asp net, Estoy batallando un poco en la parte de expiración de mi token, me funciona bien cuando configuro que expire en un dia(`Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)`), pero cuando quiero hacer prubas de que expire en minutos(`Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)`), me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En este caso le coloque que expirara en 1 minuto.

Este es mi método para generar el JWT:

```
    private string GenerateJwtToken(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.GetSection(key: "JwtConfig:Secret").Value);

        //Token descriptor
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(type: "Id", value: user.Id),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, value: user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, value:user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, value: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, value: DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
            }),

            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        };

        var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return jwtToken;
    }
```

Y asi esta configurado en mi clase Program:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
{
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection(key: "JwtConfig:Secret").Value);

jwt.SaveToken = true;
jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    ValidateIssuer = false, //for dev
    ValidateAudience = false, //for dev
    RequireAudience = false, //for dev
    RequireExpirationTime = true, // for dev -- needs to be updated when refresh token
    ValidateLifetime = true
};
});
```

espero me puedan apoyar diciendo que tengo mal, no he podido encontrar una solución para mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver mi problema con la siguiente configuración:

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(IdentityUser user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(type: "Id", value: user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, value: user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, value:user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, value: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, value: DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Secret").Value));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return jwt;
    }
```

Espero les ayude para algunos compañeros.